# XPath in Google Sheets producing #N/A

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I was currently using this XPath in Google Sheets and it’s now saying imported content is empty.

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.sportsline.com/nfl/odds/", "//div[@class='row-group']")
```

I have an HTML that works, but this table worked best for my other formulas. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try this `=IMPORTXML("http://www.sportsline.com/nfl/odds/", "//div[@class='odds-data-row']")`

Comment: Could you please also elaborate what data point you're trying to import form the site? Please try and share specific details.
Alternately, you can use this chrome plugin to point to a specific point on the site and get the XPATH yourself - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-finder/ihnknokegkbpmofmafnkoadfjkhlogph

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ That is also coming up as N/A.

Comment: @SourabhChoraria  this is how the data would come across using the importXML in OP.  https://imgur.com/l5V1Y08